# Where can I buy a larger than usual 13x4x4 pull man pan?

Tags: baking, pan, shopping

I want to make Italian style pain de mie bread for sandwich which is much larger size than  the usual 13x4x4 pull man pan available on the market.

Where can I find a larger size baking pan for pain de mie? Are there any alternatives to achieve this goal?

Comment: I looked and looked. I love my pullman pans, but I can't find one larger than 4X4X13 inches. What you can do is approximate one by using a larger "regular" pan with an aluminum foil lid and something flat with some heft (a sheet pan or baking stone?). Welcome to Seasoned Advice. I edited out your signature just because we don't do that here. I will write an answer once I actually try the makeshift lid thing.

Answer (score 1):

Like this one
[Wilton Aluminum Loaf Pan](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00024WNOU)?
Or are there some other requirements?

Comment: WOW! I looked and looked! :) No lid though. The lips on the top would be problematic for trying to fabricate one. [Here's one with a lid](http://www.amazon.com/Focus-Foodservice-Commercial-Bakeware-Pullman/dp/B004DDNDUY/ref=pd_sim_79_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=031R859JAQF7VMPNCF16)

Answer (score 1):

There is a 16x4x4 inch pullman on Amazon (see James's answer and my comment). In another comment, I suggested a workaround.

Well, curiosity piqued, I tried the workaround.

I preheated the baking stone with the oven. This is an awesome recipe from [King Arthur Flour](http://www.kingarthurflour.com/recipes/honey-oat-pain-de-mie-recipe) and a go to, so I can say that the workaround gets the same results as an actual pain de mie pan. This is a pullman, but without the lid.

That being the case, I question spending the money on the large pullman.

[image: 1] [image: 2] [image: 3] [image: 4] [image: 5]